# Questions about Namba forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am looking at Jech's proof of properties of Namba forcing. The conditions consist of perfect subtrees of $\omega_2^{<\omega}$, where perfect means every node has $\omega_2$ many (not necessarily immediate) successors. The following is a key step in showing the forcing doesn't add reals (so $\omega_1$ is preserved): suppose $T\Vdash\dot{f}:\omega\rightarrow 2$ is a function, inductively for $s\in\omega_2^{<\omega}$ construct $T_s$ and $\alpha_s\in 2$ such that:

(i) $T_\emptyset\subset T$, and if $s_1\subset s_2$ then $T_{s_1}\supset T_{s_2}$,

(ii) if $s\in\omega_2^n$ then $T_s\Vdash\dot{f}(n)=\alpha_s$,

(iii) $T_s$ has stem $t_s$, namely every node in $T_s$ is compatible with $t_s$, and if $s_1,s_2\in\omega_2^n$ are different then $t_{s_1},t_{s_2}$ are incompatible.

Jech then remarks that (iii) implies any condition $T'$ extending $\bigcup_{s\in\omega_2^n}T_s$ is compatible with one of the $T_s$. **Why?** This would be true if $T'$ contains one of the stem $t_s$ (e.g., if the stems have bounded height, but I can't see if that can be arranged). Is it impossible that every node in $T'$ is strictly below some $t_s$?

Other questions: what are some other references for basic properties of Namba forcing? There seems to be another variant of Namba forcing, such that above the stem every node has $\omega_2$ many immediate successors; is that equivalent to Jech's definition? Does Namba forcing preserve $\omega_3$?

Comment: Isn't it that if every node in $T'$ is below $t_s$, then $T'$ is stronger than $T_s$?

Comment: @HanulJeon Could you clarify? $T'$ extends (i.e. is contained in) the union so for every $t\in T'$, there exists $s\in\omega_2^n$ s.t. either $t\subset t_s$ or $t\supset t_s$. I want to show that the second case must happen for some $s$.

Comment: AFAIK every $T'$ has a stem, say it $t_{T'}$. If $T'\le \bigcup_{s\in \omega^n_2} T_s$, then $t_{T'}$ is compatible with one of (and unique) $t_s$. Then $t_{T'}\supseteq t_s$ or otherwise $T'$ branches before $t_s$ starts, which contradicts with $T'\le \bigcup_{s\in \omega^n_2} T_s$ (if we adjusted all of $t_s$ have the same length.)

Comment: @HanulJeon That's what I asked in my second-to-last paragraph: can we assume the stems $t_s$ have the same length...It's not clear to me how to do that. We can certainly do it for the first level $s\in\omega_2^1$, but to have it at the second level it seems we have to shrink the first level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't quite need *all* of the stems to have the same length. Rather, you inductively construct the stems $t_s$, so that for each $s$ all the stems $t_{s\frown i}$ have the same length $h_s$. At each step you do this just like in the base case (pick $\omega_2$ incompatible extensions of $t_s$, strengthen to decide $\dot{f}(n+1)$, and realize that there are only countably many levels to hold all your $\omega_2$ many stems).

With this additional property, let's try to prove Jech's claim. It's instructive to first look at the case $n=1$, so pick a tree $T'$ contained in $\bigcup_{i<\omega_2} T_i$. If $b_\emptyset$ is any node of height $h_\emptyset$ then it must be one of the $t_i$, since those are the only nodes in $\bigcup_i T_i$ of that height. Therefore $T'$ is compatible with that $T_i$.

More generally, let's take $T'\subseteq \bigcup_{s\in \omega_2^{n+1}} T_s$. Let $b_0$ be any node in $T'$ of height $h_\emptyset$. It must be one of the $t_i$ for $i<\omega_2$, since those are the only nodes in $\bigcup_{s\in \omega_2^{n+1}} T_s$ of that height. Call that stem $b_0=t_{i_0}$. Next, let $b_1$ be an extension of $b_0$ in $T'$ of height $h_{i_0}$. By construction, the only nodes in $\bigcup_{s\in \omega_2^{n+1}} T_s$ above $t_{i_0}$ of height $h_{i_0}$ are the stems $t_{i_0\frown i}$ for $i<\omega_2$, so $b_1$ must be one of those.

Continuing on in this way, we can show that $T'$ contains one of the $t_s$ for $s\in\omega_2^{n+1}$, and so is compatible with that $T_s$.

---

I don't know of a good source on Namba forcing, but Shelah has some material in *Proper and Improper Forcing* (specifically, chapters X and XI). In particular, he mentions your other version of Namba forcing and proves that they are not equivalent (Claim XI.4.2: neither adds generics for the other).

Regarding $\omega_3$, any forcing that preserves $\omega_1$ and makes $\omega_2$ of countable cofinality will collapse $\omega_3$. See Claim XI.4.3 of Shelah's book. The same claim also states that both versions of Namba forcing can consistently have the $\omega_4$-cc.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a reference that shows Namba forcing preserves $\omega_1$ even without CH?

Comment: @newaccount See Theorem XI.3.6 and Lemma XI.4.4 in Shelah's book. Alternatively, [here](https://mikepawliuk.ca/2012/10/18/namba-forcing-with-arnie-miller/) are some notes from a class with Arnie Miller that suggest a more transparent argument (but I haven't thought it through).

Comment: @newaccount I [have written up](https://andreas-lietz.github.io/blog/NambaBlog.html) a quite short proof that shows Namba forcing preserves $\omega_1$ and even of the somewhat stronger fact that Namba forcing preserves stationary subsets of $\omega_1$.

Shelah proves something much stronger and consequently much more complicated in his book.